# Program freezes while catching signal

Tags: c, linux, windows, signals

I'm trying to catch signal in my program in order to display backtrace. It works pretty well many times, but for some signals it freezes.
My code:

```
static void signal_handled(int s) {
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp single
#endif
    {
    g_printf("Error, signal %d:\n", s);
    const gchar *visit = _("Please report this bug to: " PACKAGE_BUGREPORT);
    switch (s) {
    case SIGSEGV:
    case SIGFPE:
    case SIGABRT:
    case SIGILL:
        g_printf(ANSI_COLOR_RED"%s\n"ANSI_COLOR_RESET, visit);
    }

#if (!defined _WIN32 && defined HAVE_EXECINFO_H)
        int i;
        void *stack[STACK_DEPTH];

        size_t size = backtrace(stack, sizeof(stack) / sizeof(void*));

        char **message = backtrace_symbols(stack, size);
        if (message != NULL && message[0] != NULL) {
            for (i = 0; i < size && message != NULL; ++i) {
                g_printf("[#%i] in %s\n", i, message[i]);
            }
            free(message);
        }
#else
    unsigned int i;
    void *stack[STACK_DEPTH];
    unsigned short size;
    SYMBOL_INFO *symbol;
    HANDLE process;

    process = GetCurrentProcess();

    SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);

    size = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, sizeof(stack) / sizeof(void*), stack, NULL);
    symbol = (SYMBOL_INFO*) calloc(sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + 256 * sizeof(char), 1);
    symbol->MaxNameLen = 255;
    symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        SymFromAddr(process, (DWORD64)(stack[i]), 0, symbol);

        g_printf("[#%i]: in %s\n", i, symbol->Name);
    }

    free(symbol);
#endif
    }
    undo_flush();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void signals_init() {
#ifndef _WIN32
    signal(SIGHUP, signal_handled);
    signal(SIGQUIT, signal_handled);
    signal(SIGBUS, signal_handled);
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handled);
    signal(SIGTRAP, signal_handled);
#endif
    signal(SIGABRT, signal_handled);
    signal(SIGFPE, signal_handled);
    signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handled);
    signal(SIGTERM, signal_handled);
    signal(SIGILL, signal_handled);
}
```

The program freezes on the first memory allocation. So here, it will freeze on `char **message = backtrace_symbols(stack, size);` and therefore no backtrace are displayed, and user wait for the end of programm that never happen.
Again, it is not signal dependant. Some signals 11 will be ok, some not. Same for 6, and so on ...

Is there a safe way to display backtraces? Why the program freezes before displaying it?

Comment: Your signal handler is definitely calling a few non-signal-handler-safe functions and I bet most of the non-standard ones are unsafe too...

Comment: Read https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Comment: OK, but I think that at least SIGSEGV is standard? Because I even have the issue with it.
However I will read your page.

Comment: @lock: No, what Shawn meant is that a signal handler is a special type of function, in which only certain functions can be used safely.  These functions are called *async-signal safe*, and are listed in the above function.  You use e.g. `g_printf()`, `malloc()`, `free()`, none of which are async-signal safe, and could be the reason why it freezes.  (Note that the signal handler context is complex, so even if you "test" that some functions work in some cases, does not mean they will work in all cases. You can only trust async-signal safe functions here.)

Comment: Oh thanks @None!! I got it.
A question, I would expect that the backtrace_symbols function would be safe. But as it freezes on it, I don't know how I can do something without it.

Comment: You could wake up a thread that's waiting on a semaphore, which gets the signal number in a global variable. Then, since these cases are meant to be terminal, just put the current thread to sleep and wait for the tragic end...

Answer (score 0):

Following the advices of @Shawn and @None I found that the solution is to avoid the use of the `backtrace_symbols` function. `backtrace_symbols_fd` is better as it does not use malloc.
Better things are sometimes the easiest.

Comment: It's good to keep in mind that you need implementation-specific guarantees to call any function from within a signal handler. Per [footnote 188 of the C11 standard:](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  [POSIX systems provide a list of async-signal-safe functions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03)  If you know the details of what your code does along with internal implementation details of functions, you can "get away with" some things...